# How to make hidden text in Rich text box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hidden, rtf

I am using Windows application for my project. Now I want to make some text hidden in Rich Text box control.

So is there any functionality to make hidden some text in Rich Text Box control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's text no one can modify that you don't want them to see, put it in a label and set the visible property to false.

If you want to capture their entry into the textbox but not have it show up in the UI, you can use the keypress/keydown events.

Answer (score 0):

Set the color of the text to match the background color of the textbox. That would effectively "hide" it.

Comment: unless they selected it, copied it, and pasted it into notepad?  the text he wants to 'hide' is still in the textbox...

Comment: @Beth - Not sure what you mean. What does Notepad have to do with his question? If the text is *in* the text box he should be able to change the font color, regardless of whether it was copied/pasted from another application.

Comment: no, I meant the other way around.  If he wants to keep the text in the text box hidden, and all he does is change the text color, the text can be 'shown' by copying it from his textbox and pasting it somewhere else, like Notepad.

Comment: @Beth of course it can! Notepad shows black text. If you copy red white or blue text you can still paste it into Notepad and it will be black. But this has nothing to do with the question so still not sure why we're even discussing it. He asked how to hide text in a rich text box.

Comment: it depends on what he means by 'hide.'  If he really wants it 'hidden' so it can't be copied or pasted, he needs to take a different approach.  I don't know why he wants some text hidden, but if it's for some reason like they're entering a password and he doesn't want it showing, then changing the font color could still expose the text.